# Wind wall of depression

Tags: wind

It's a wind map from the ICON (13km grid) model of the Atlantique ocean of this 7 July 2023. I get that there's two depression near each other interacting but how there's only a very thin line as the resulte of the interaction ? If it's not an artifact from the model, why is it SO thin and not align with the center of these depression ?

I've also checked with other models (NEMS (4km) and UKV (2km)) and it's the same thing...

Just so you know, I'm an engineering student, so it's not my main stuff by I'm still interested by the subject !
[image: Strange thing the wind is doing in the Atlantic ocean]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the synoptic chart from the UK Met Office, the thin line in your picture corresponds to a frontal system. Immediately to the west of Ireland there is a cold front (blue line with triangles) and to the southwest of that, and inline with that, is a warm front (red line with semicircles).

[image]

Comment: So the warm front is blocked by the wind from the other depression, thus creating the thin line of no wind, right ?